# Is there a computation that takes the same amount of time to run on any computer?

Tags: computability, time-complexity

I'm looking for research that has been done towards finding types of computations that take the same exact amount of time to run, regardless the amount of computing power one has.

I've been thinking about also computations that might require external factors - for example being able to hash tomorrow's newspaper is a type of computation that takes the same amount of time.

However I'm looking for something that can run on computers with certainty (tomorrow's newspaper might not come out at all).

Any thoughts?

**EDIT** what I'm looking for is not something that runs in *exactly* the same amount of time. For example, a computation that counts to 10 would be ok, as it would roughly take 10 seconds on every computer. What I need is a way to arrive at a certain result only after having waited 10 seconds. Imagine that I have a password protected key, and the only way to see the password was to wait 10 seconds.

Comment: "Algorithms" are not something that can be computed.

Comment: sorry you're right. changed "algorithms" to "computation".

Comment: Hashing tomorrow's newspaper doesn't take the same amount of time on any computer. Sure, any computer has to wait until tomorrow to receive the data but that just means that a fast computer might take, say, 24 hours and one millisecond, compared to a slow computer taking 24 hours and 300 milliseconds.

Comment: Right indeed. I was also thinking of using things such as planets position at specific intervals. But I guess that suffers from the same slow/fast computer problem for measuring it.

Comment: I've edited to show my use case. I doesn't have to be exactly 10 seconds.

Comment: its part of the basic teaching of CS that virtually every computer computes the "same thing" in "different times". the closest to what you want is probably P-time equivalence. otherwise what you want (and you dont say _why_) is impossible even almost by physics principles. the closest might be an atomic clock or other device measuring physical universe constants etc....   note that most modern computers do have a highly accurate _clock_ built in, usually based on measuring crystal oscillations, on which the entire computation is based/ timed....

Comment: Any non-halting computation will take the same amount of time on any computer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might be interested in timed-release cryptography, where some secret is released to the world only after a specific point in time, and having a faster computer doesn't help you learn the secret any quicker.

If you search on timed-release cryptography, time-lock cryptography, and time capsule cryptography on [Cryptography.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), you'll find a bunch of information on the topic.  For instance:

- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/606/351
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3064/351
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/932/351
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26405/351
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2507/351
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15140/351
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12580/351
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5831/351

I suspect it might also be possible to achieve what you want by using the Bitcoin block-chain, transactions with a user script, and some cleverness.

Comment: Ha.  Using the blockchain would slow down the processing to the point that the speed of the computer would be much less important.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain of what you are after, so I am giving you below pointers to various related areas of research that may answer your quesry. To be true, they fit your examples more closely than the tags you have chosen. But then, I do not see how your examples and your tags can fit together. So I am waiting for your reaction (after all, it is related to reactive programming) to understand better, and possibly suggest changing the tags.

It seems that what you are after is event driven programming. There is
a wikipedia page on [event driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) and another one on
[event-driven architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture). The flow of execution is controled by
events, which may be external events. All you expect from the computer
is to be fast enough so as to be ready for the next event.  So this
type of programming is alsi linked to real-time programming, when
events external to the computer are taken into consideration.

It is unclear whether you are concerned with external events, since you give the  newspaper example, and then say that it might be a bad example, because you cannot be sure of external events. But these techniques can use all kinds of events, including internal interrupts, mouse clicks, clock driven signals, etc.

It is also linked to [reactive systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_system), [synchronous programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_programming_language) and [dataflow programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming).

There has been considerable research on this topic, and a large number of programming languages and formalisms were developed. Among others, you may look for
programming languages such as [Esterel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esterel), [Lustre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_%28programming_language%29), or [Signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGNAL_%28programming_language%29).

I guess these references should give you enough starting point, if my answer meets what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think that this is what they are after, since it "needs to run with certainty" from which I make out it can *not* depend on an external event.

Comment: The question is ambiguous on that. Why use this example at all, if it is always wrong? Besides, the kind of programming I am considering my be used with internal event. And the fact that an event may fail to occur can be dismissed as possible for all events, including that the sun will rise tomorrow. We just work on assumptions, possibly with fallbacks in case of failure.

Comment: Right, what I'm looking for is more of a "proof-of-work" system. But rather than requiring the proof of a certain amount of work (which varies based on how much computing power one has), it is based on time: prove to me you waited 10 seconds (or whatever) to run this computation.

Comment: @LucaMatteis Sorry. I just learned what is a "proof-of-work" system. The idea is to
enforce waiting and have a way to check it. This requires a third
party issuing certificates containing event specific data. The third
party could be within the computer if it can sit there protected
agaisnt tampering (special chip?). It could work with a clock and an
encryption system so that its certificates cannot be forged, such
assymetric cryptography, using a private key internally with a public
key available to you. There should be a way of checking that the
public key is an official one.

Comment: @LucaMatteis So my guess is that cryptographic techniques might help you., as I tried to sketch briefly. But I have no pointer to existing work of the kind, other than the work on DRM and other Technical Measures of Protection. Possibly, a non-harmful variant used for such certification only could be developed. I am not sure, and I feel rather queasy about the whole idea. Of course, an alternative would be to use an external service that delivers such certifications upon request.

Comment: I vaguely remember an axiomatic theory of computation, started by Blum. There you find surprising results like proof that there are problems that take longer to solve on a Cray than on the slowest inplementation of BASIC on your netbook, and problems for which there isn't a fastest program: given any program solving the problem, you can find a faster one.

Comment: @LucaMatteis I think my previous suggestions do not work. And I check some of the references of the other answer: they do not meet your requirement either, because they keep the processor busy, which seems to be what you want to avoid. I guess your purpose is not to keep the computer idle, but to prevent it from working on a specific problem, though it received the information to start working.